# LoopBack Vs Breeze.JS to use with Node.JS

Tags: breeze, loopbackjs

Are both [LoopBack](http://loopback.io/getting-started/) and [Breeze.JS](http://www.getbreezenow.com/) to do the same to persist the data from the Node.JS client applications to database like MSSQL, Oracle etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoopBack is an exciting company with smart people.

I don't know much about LoopBack's data management offerings and, as one of the principals behind breeze, I don't feel comfortable making comparisons anyway.

I do think it's wise to consider every technology choice in the context of your broad business and application needs.

Let me suggest some areas to investigate:

- What database(s) do you care about? How does the product actually work with those databases?
- Do you need/want support on the server for

  - transactions
  - validation during save
  - batch save requests (mix of entity types and insert/update/delete)
  - batch query requests
- Do you need/want support on the client for

  - client-side caching and events
  - tracking entity change state
  - property change notification
  - property and entity validation
  - automated entity graphs (e.g. just-in-time population and maintenance of entity navigation properties)
  - typed representation of sub-documents ("complex types")
  - original value tracking (ability to cancel pending changes)
  - serialization of entity graphs with circular references.
- Will you need to consider integration with non-Node client or server technologies? With legacy applications and services?
- Is there both developer and API documentation? How much? Does it provide the kind and quality of guidance you'll need?
- How many questions have been asked on StackOverflow? What questions are people asking about the technology on StackOverflow? Are they the kinds of questions you'll be asking as you build your app? What do you think of the answers?
- What do you require of customer support *for the specific technologies* you seek?
- How established and stable is the technology you seek? Is the vendor well-versed in the issues and concerns of someone trying to solve these problems? Does this matter to you?
- What are people actually doing with this technology? Look beyond the customer list. Find out whether these customers are doing what you want to do.
- What is the vendor's experience designing and supporting the kinds of applications you intend to build with its technology?